# Setting environment variable in a docker container

Tags: json, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to set environment variables in a docker container but I get the following error

```
 starting container process caused "exec: \"-e\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Here is how I set the variables

```
docker run image -e ENV_VAR= '{"a":{"b":"c"}}' -p 3000:3000
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker command is order sensitive. Everything after the image name is the command you want to run inside the container. Place the image name after the flags to the run command:

```
docker run -e ENV_VAR='{"a":{"b":"c"}}' -p 3000:3000 image
```

Comment: That gives me another error docker: invalid reference format.

Comment: @user_mda your image name is wrong, or you have something else wrong in your command. Without a real example I cannot say which.

Comment: Nevermind it works , I had an extra space in between the env variable.